# Converting EMF format to PNG or JPG.

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to make a android document viewer. I need to convert Emf format to jpg or png format. If anyone knows how to do it or if there is any open source project for this then please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [EMF file format documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230514.aspx) has been released by Microsoft a while ago, so the hardcore approach would be to code up the whole thing yourself.

Fortunately, you're not the first to ask this question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861400/need-to-convert-emf-to-jpeg-png-file-formats-using-java) for suggestions that might be worth following up.