# Convert WMF to PNG/BMP/JPG

Tags: java, image-processing, png, wmf

How can I convert one WMF file to PNG/BMP/JPG format with custom output resolution?

Example: Take WMF file and outputs PNG file with 2000x2000 px.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to reliably convert this format is by using the Windows' GDI API, what is your operating system ? I've seen an online converter (zamzar.com) that seems to handle the format, but I'm not sure how well.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu with Java 6

Comment: Then you will need to luck, i.e., your WMF files are simple and don't use newer API calls from GDI(+).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the excelent Batik ( http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/ ) lib to achieve this. But you will need to follow this steps:

1. Convert the WMF file to SVG using the WMFTranscoder
2. Convert the SVG to JGP using the JPGTranscoder

WMF >> SVG >> JPG

Here is a discussion on coderanch about it: http://www.coderanch.com/t/422868/java/java/converting-WMF-Windows-Meta-File

Comment: Interesting, does it guarantee that it always work even using a operating system different than Windows ? In that case, does it also  fully support the newer WMF formats: EMF and EMF+ ?

Comment: Ah, now I see a footnote on its page: "Windows Metafiles (WMF) are supported through classes in Apache Batik. At the moment, support for this format is experimental and may not always work as expected."

Comment: @mmgp, yeah it works on Linux too, last year i did something like this and it works perfect. About the newer WMF format i dont know, i've only used the WMF exported by autocad.

Comment: @mmgp, sometimes batik cant convert some objects and gives warnings, but this is best way that i can find to do this conversion...

Comment: There is the `unoconv` tool which might be better, there is also  libgdiplus from Mono which might be better too.

Answer (score 2):

WMF, EMF and EMF+ are integral parts of slideshows, therefore I've developed a renderer for those as part of Apache POI. As for the upcoming POI-4.1.2 this is still work in progress - if you have any rendering issues, please upload your file in a [new bug report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI&component=SL+Common&short_desc=EMF+WMF+rendering+issue&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All) in our bugzilla.

The main description can be found in the [POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/ppt-wmf-emf-renderer.html).

Here is an excerpt:

### #1 - Use PPTX2PNG via file or stdin

For file system access, you need to save your slideshow/WMF/EMF/EMF+ first to disc and then call `PPTX2PNG.main()` with the corresponding parameters.

for `stdin` access, you need to redirect `System.in` before:

```
/* the file content */
InputStream is = ...;
/* Save and set System.in */
InputStream oldIn = System.in;
try {
    System.setIn(is);
    String[] args = {
        "-format", "png", // png,gif,jpg,svg or null for test
        "-outdir", new File("out/").getCanonicalPath(),
        "-outfile", "export.png",
        "-fixside", "long",
        "-scale", "800",
        "-ignoreParse",
        "stdin"
    };
    PPTX2PNG.main(args);
} finally {
    System.setIn(oldIn);
}
```

### #2 - Render WMF / EMF / EMF+ via the *Picture classes

```
File f = samples.getFile("santa.wmf");
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f)) {
    // for WMF
    HwmfPicture wmf = new HwmfPicture(fis);
    // for EMF / EMF+
    HemfPicture emf = new HemfPicture(fis);
    Dimension dim = wmf.getSize();
    int width = Units.pointsToPixel(dim.getWidth());
    // keep aspect ratio for height
    int height = Units.pointsToPixel(dim.getHeight());
    double max = Math.max(width, height);
    if (max > 1500) {
    width *= 1500/max;
    height *= 1500/max;
    }
    BufferedImage bufImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = bufImg.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
    wmf.draw(g, new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,width,height));
    g.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(bufImg, "PNG", new File("bla.png"));
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. Just as a note, I had to pull in the poi-scratchpad artifact (as opposed to just "poi") to get the classes under the org.apache.poi.hemf package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [different tools](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/wmf) for this format. You can choose for example GIMP. In Java you have a [library for converting WMF files](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/libwmf.html).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a walkaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72405526/3552975), for Java I learned that I can run shell command following answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16482601/3552975). For WMF, convert it to EMF first following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35469318/3552975).