# .wmf to .emf conversion just by changing extension?

Tags: windows, format, wmf

Hi I'm trying to convert from .wmf to .emf, I have read that they are similar, and it might be possible to just change the extension file from .wmf to .emf, but it didn't stated clearly if it will work. thanks for the help.

Comment: Changing a file's extension doesn't "convert" anything. The only way that could possibly work is a) some WMF files are valid EMF files; or b) that by renaming it you fool some particular program into *trying* to open it as a different format, and recovering from errors sufficiently to give the desired result.

Comment: well, since windows metafile, and enchanted metafile, only difference is that emf has more characteristic there is a chance that it might work, but I am not sure that's why I am wondering if it could work or if someone has tried, I am concerned about those errors that it might appear :/

Answer (score 1):

While WMF and EMF files are essentially the same, EMF files have a few extra commands the can use. So 'converting' WMF to EMF by renaming should work, but EMF to WMF may cause issues.