# Convert EMF+ (not WMF / EMF) file to PNG in java

Tags: java, svg, png, freehep

Problem:

I have a an image of Enhanced Metafile Fromat Plus Extension **EMF+**. I need to convert this file to to a **PNG** image file with java.

Attempts to resolve problem in java:

1. `Apache Batik` does not support **EMF+** format (Batik supports **WMF** only format).
2. `FreeHEP` does not support **EMF+** too. It can convert **EMF** to **SVG** and then **SVG** to **PNG**. I hoped it can help:

   ```
   EMF2SVG.main( new String[] {inputMetaFileName,ontputSvgFileName});
   ```

   this statement must convert **EMF** to **SVG**, but gives an exception:

   > java.lang.NullPointerException at   org.freehep.graphicsio.exportchooser.AbstractExportFileType.getGraphics(AbstractExportFileType.java:261) at org.freehep.graphicsio.exportchooser.AbstractExportFileType.exportToFile(AbstractExportFileType.java:248) at org.freehep.graphicsio.exportchooser.AbstractExportFileType.exportToFile(AbstractExportFileType.java:282)
   >   at org.freehep.graphicsio.emf.EMFConverter.export(EMFConverter.java:81)
   >   at org.freehep.graphicsio.emf.EMF2SVG.main(EMF2SVG.java:27)
3. I used code from [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-dev/201501.mbox/%3CCAKps1KYNdVE4tuQM97Vn85KvSkUr4+8cRjE4w1s_asOHUFujqg@mail.gmail.com%3E):

   ```
   try {
       // read the EMF file
       EMFRenderer emfRenderer = new EMFRenderer( new EMFInputStream(
           new ByteArrayInputStream(emfBytes)));

       EMFPanel emfPanel = new EMFPanel();
       emfPanel.setRenderer(emfRenderer);

       // prepare Graphics2D
       FileOutputStream svg = new FileOutputStream("svg.svg");
       SVGGraphics2D graphics2D = new SVGGraphics2D (svg, emfPanel);

       // export to SVG
       graphics2D.startExport();
       emfPanel.print(graphics2D);
       graphics2D.endExport();
       svg.flush();
       svg.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   This code creates **SVG** file, but it file has no image.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279104/convert-wmf-to-png-bmp-jpg ?

Comment: A little. EMF and WMF are various formats. WMFTranscoder does not support EMF and batik does not have EMFTranscoder. I try to find other way to convert WMF to PNG (or JPEG). I found code here [link](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-dev/201501.mbox/%3CCAKps1KYNdVE4tuQM97Vn85KvSkUr4+8cRjE4w1s_asOHUFujqg@mail.gmail.com%3E) but it does not work. I used freeHeep EMF2SVG but it does not work too.

Comment: Waht is your question? If it's is there a tool that does EMF conversion it's off topic and if it's can you write an EMF converter for me as an answer it's too broad.

Comment: @RobertLongson i need programmatically to convert EMF image to other viewable format. java code should not call command-line tools. it can use only vector graphics libraries. I found only Batik and FreeHEP but they did not help me. Maybe somebody can use Batik or FreeHEP or other library to convert EMF.