# How to have node convert `.emf` to `.jpg` (or anything I can place on a webpage)

Tags: node.js, image-processing

Stuck in this weird situation at work. I have .doc files I'm parsing with Node.JS. They have photos in them that are `.emf` I want to display in my web app. I have no issue getting the emf file out of the word doc, but I can't figure out how to display it on a webpage. Simply embedding as is didn't work. I tried to find a utility to convert them automatically but with no luck. I thought of converting them myself but can't find any tecnhical info on the `.emf` file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

EMF (WMF) are the SVG like formats of the 1990's.

I can't give you the full solution in this space but [checkout this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562201/convert-emf-not-wmf-emf-file-to-png-in-java) that uses [Apache Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)

If you don't want to build it yourself perhaps try the paid version of [converters](https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-emf)

If you can't afford I would recommend to host the Batik and make a service endpoint and make calls to generate the desired format from EMF. It may turn out actually faster.