# The attribute "d" of the element <path> is invalid in a SVG to PNG converter using Batik

Tags: java, svg, png, batik, wmf

I am trying to convert WMF to PNG using the Batik library, and the first part where I convert from WMF to PNG is working okay but when I try to convert SVG to  PNG it gives me the "The attribute "d" of the element  is invalid.

An example of the path element would be:

```
<path d="MNaN NaN LNaN...NaN Z" stroke ="none" />
```

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: NaN means not a number so, Batik is entirely correct that the d attribute is invalid.

Comment: Oh I see thank you. Is there any way I can avoid that when converting from WMF to SVG?

Comment: Write your own WMF to SVG converter then you're sure it will work, or if the one you're using is open source, download its code and fix it.

Comment: Inkscape has a WMF import function you could try.

Comment: Will try that, thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the [Apache POI renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130964/2066598). If you have render problems, just open a ticket in our bugzilla (and attach the wmf files) or alternatively send me an email with your not-to-be-open-sourced files.